# How to call functions dynamically play framework scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I have created separate file for each function in IntelliJ Scala using Play framework. How do I call each of functions?

```
@services = { html code of service.scala.html  }
@navigation ={ html code of navigation.scala.html }
```

I have contact.scala and many more functions like this.

My application.controller

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
  def navigation = Action {
    Ok(views.html.navigation())
  }
  def services = Action {
    Ok(views.html.services())
  }
}
```

My routes

```
GET        /                    controllers.Application.index
GET        /navigation          controllers.Application.naigation
GET        /services            controllers.Application.services
```

I even have a index.scala.html and main.scala.html. Now how do I call this all in one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a defined template in any other view. For example if you have *services.scala.html* in your *views* directory you insert it by putting a following line in any view:

```
@views.html.services()
```

Notice that you don't have to define a route or an action mapping in order to include it in a view.

Comment: I have to just put this nothing else ?

Comment: If I had understood your problem right, yes, that is all. If it's not what you want you need to describe your problem more briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a template that include all other html contents like,

```
@(..)(navigation: Html)(services: Html) {
.
.
<html>
  <body>
   @navigation // bring in your individual html contents here or where ever you want.
   @services
   .
   .
  </body>
</html>
}
```

Comment: should i call it in main.scala ?

Comment: Your controller will call/render the html file, like, index.render(..) which in-tern can call the code I specified above like @main(..){..}{..}, if the above code is in main.scala.html file.